# Exit functions in C

Tags: c, posix, exit

What is the difference between **exit()**, **_exit()** and **_Exit()** in C?

How do I decide  which to use?

On bash,

> man 2 exit

gave me the page _EXIT(2), whereas

> man 3 exit

gave the page EXIT(3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`exit()` terminating after cleanup.

`_exit()` terminating immediately after call.

If you have some stack corrupted while `exit()` function was called program may close with Segmentation Fault, if you are use `_exit()`, program exit in quick mode.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wdz5232.aspx you have

`exit()` - Performs complete C library termination procedures, terminates the process, and exits with the supplied status code.

`_exit()` - Performs quick C library termination procedures, terminates the process, and exits with the supplied status code.

`_cexit()` - Performs complete C library termination procedures and returns to the caller, but does not terminate the process.

`_c_exit()` - Performs quick C library termination procedures and returns to the caller, but does not terminate the process.

Comment: OK, but what's the difference between complete and quick termination⸮

Comment: please elaborate what should be used when.

Comment: Call `exit()`. The others are implementation details, and are generally not as useful outside of certain rare conditions when building frameworks.

Answer (score 7):

Normative in C99 are `exit` and `_Exit`.

The difference between the two is that `exit` also executes the handlers that may be registered with `atexit` and closes streams etc whereas `_Exit` doesn't call the `atexit` routines and may or may not close streams properly.

`_exit` is from POSIX and has similar properties as `_Exit` with the difference that it is guaranteed to close streams properly.

In summary, whenever you can you should use `exit`, this is the cleanest way to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

From man:

> exit:
> All functions registered with atexit(3) and on_exit(3) are  called,  in
>          the  reverse  order  of their registration ... All open stdio(3) streams are flushed and  closed.   Files  created  by tmpfile(3) are removed.
>
> _exit:
> The function _exit() is like exit(3), but does not call  any  functions
>          registered  with  atexit(3) or on_exit(3).  Whether it flushes standard
>          I/O buffers and removes temporary  files  created  with  tmpfile(3)  is
>          implementation-dependent. On  the other hand, _exit() does close open
>          file descriptors ...

Answer (score 0):

1.exit() :
      it's cleanup the work like closing file descriptor, file stream and so on,
2._exit() :
      it's not cleanup the work like closing the file descriptor,file stream and so on

These are the major difference of exit() and _exit().

am i rectified ur answer

Comment: _exit does close file descriptors.

Comment: No, the kernel does. _exit just terminates the process. _exit's main feature is that it does nothing but tell the kernel to terminate the process.