# Can exit() fail to terminate process?

Tags: c, linux, process, exit

I have a registered a signal handler in my program. Upon receiving an undesired signal (SIGABRT), i call 'exit(-1)' in signal handler to exit the process. But as noticed on few ocassions, it calls exit() but fails to terminate the process.

The  issue was randomly generated and I strongly suspect on execution of exit().

Can there be any reasons or cases in which the exit() can fail to terminate the process.

Thanks.

Comment: I most certainly advise you to look for another cause for the bug than a function like `exit`. Almost always, when you think there is a bug in the compiler or the standard library etc, it's your own mistake that is causing the error.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Mandar isn't asking about a bug in the implementation, or suggesting that one exists. The question is whether `exit` is specified to always terminate the program, and the answer is no (and especially not if called from a signal handler).

Comment: Why not just set the handler for SIGABRT to exit()?  Whatever other things you are doing in the signal handler, do them in an atexit() call.

Comment: @William Pursell: If a process is going to be terminated by a signal, functions registered by atexit() aren't going to be called unless someone was foolish enough to call exit() from the signal handler. Re-entrancy's a pill.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Are you calling `exit()` from the signal handler?

In `man 7 signal`, section **Async-signal-safe functions** you can see all the functions that are guaranteed to work when called from an signal handler:

> A  signal  handler  function  must be very careful, since processing elsewhere may be interrupted at
>          some arbitrary point in the execution of the program.  POSIX has the concept of "safe function".  If
>          a  signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and handler calls an unsafe function, then
>          the behavior of the program is undefined.
>
> POSIX.1-2004 (also known as POSIX.1-2001 Technical Corrigendum  2)  requires  an  implementation  to
>          guarantee that the following functions can be safely called inside a signal handler:

There you can see functions `_Exit()`, `_exit()` and `abort()`, but notably not `exit()`. So you should not call it from a signal handler.

The nasty thing is that even if you call an unsafe function from a signal handler (`printf()` any?) it will just work most of the time... but not always.

Comment: Calling an async-signal-unsafe function from a signal handler is *perfectly legal* unless the signal interrupted another async-signal-unsafe function. This explains the reason it works "most of the time", but it also means that you can use async-signal-unsafe functions in signal handlers even in correct, robust code if you take care to ensure that the signal handler cannot interrupt an unsafe function (for example, leaving the signal masked most of the time and only unblocking it while performing pure arithmetic or async-signal-safe library calls like file descriptor IO and `select`).

Comment: @R.. You are right, of course. But in practice is difficult to ensure that, except in very particular cases. I personally find much more convenient just to avoid the unsafe functions all together.

Comment: See also: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html

Comment: @rodrigo: It's actually fairly common if you're just using signals to make your program user-interruptable while waiting for IO - as long as you make the effort to block and unblock `SIGINT` or whatever at the right times. It's also common in multi-threaded programs if you leave the signal blocked in all but a dedicated signal-processing thread.

Comment: @R.. A little late here, but no one mentioned the C standard itself. "Calling an async-signal-unsafe function from a signal handler is *perfectly legal* ..." I wouldn't characterize it as "perfectly legal". Per [**7.1.4 Use of library functions**, paragraph 4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p4): "The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify objects with static or thread storage duration."  And [footnote 188](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Async-signal-safety is defined by POSIX, the whole point of which (as a specification for programming interfaces) is to impose additional definitions on top of C. The relevant text is under XSH 2.4.3: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are some circumstances, such as:

> The exit() function shall first call all functions registered by atexit(), in the reverse order of their registration, except that a function is called after any previously registered functions that had already been called at the time it was registered. Each function is called as many times as it was registered. If, during the call to any such function, a call to the longjmp() function is made that would terminate the call to the registered function, the behavior is undefined.
>
> If a function registered by a call to atexit() fails to return, the remaining registered functions shall not be called and the rest of the exit() processing shall not be completed. If exit() is called more than once, the behavior is undefined.

See the POSIX page on [exit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exit.html).

For more information, attach a debugger when you reach the situation and take a look at the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

I had analogous problem to the one described by [Madar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584631/mandar). I needed to perform an action for every signal and quit properly. I wondered through a couple of answers to similar issues and came up with the following explanation/solution.

**Explanation:**
One issue is that `exit()` should not be used in signal handlers because it is not one of the async-signal-safe functions (see `man signal-safety`). This is to say that it may but is not guaranteed to work in signal handlers. As a result you would need to call `_exit()`/`_Exit()` (which are async-signal-safe). These however terminate the process instantly, without calling the `atexit` callbacks and static destructors. My understanding is that for some signals a bit more cleaning can be done than what those functions provide.

**Solution:** The solution I came up with is to register your signal handler for all signals and do any extra steps. Then you can reset to the default handler and call `raise(signal_number)`, which is async-signal-safe, to re-send the singal and so execute the default handler.

Here is a working example that runs default handler only on `SIGINT`. I think this is too simple to experience the "failing" `exit()` if you used it in the handler. I tested similar code with an alternative stack to also handle `SIGSEGV`.

**Note** If you want this to work properly in multi-threaded context (e.g. multiple threads causing `SIGSEGV` at the same time) you need to take some care about synchronization. Threads share the same handler but have separate signal masking.

```
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#include <vector>

#include <unistd.h>

// The actual signal handler
extern "C" void handleSignal(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *) {
  // Cannot use printf() - not async-signal-safe 
  // For simplicity I use a single call to write here
  // though it is not guaranteed to write the whole message
  // You need to wrap it in a loop

  // Die only on Ctrl+C
  if(sig == SIGINT) {
    const char *msg = "Die\n";
    write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, ::strlen(msg));
    // Reset to use the default handler to do proper clean-up
    // If you want to call the default handler for every singal
    // You can avoid the call below by adding SA_RESETHAND to sa_flags
    signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
    raise(sig);
    return;
  }

  // Here we want to handle the signal ourselves
  // We have all the info available
  const char *msg = "Continue\n";
  write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, ::strlen(msg));
}

int main() {
  // You might want to setup your own alternative stack
  // eg. to handle SIGSEGV correctly
  // sigaltstack() + SA_ONSTACK flag in sa_flag

  // Prepare a signal action for handling any signal
  struct sigaction signal_action;

  signal_action.sa_sigaction = ::handleSignal;
  signal_action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  ::sigfillset(&signal_action.sa_mask);
  // A vector of all signals that lead to process termination by default
  // (see man -s 7 signal)
  const int TERM_SIGNALS[] = {
        SIGHUP,  SIGINT,  SIGQUIT, SIGILL,    SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGSEGV,
        SIGPIPE, SIGALRM, SIGTERM, SIGUSR1,   SIGUSR2, SIGBUS, SIGPOLL,
        SIGPROF, SIGSYS,  SIGTRAP, SIGVTALRM, SIGXCPU, SIGXFSZ};

  // Register the signal event handler for every terminating signal
  for (auto sig : TERM_SIGNALS) {
    ::sigaction(sig, &signal_action, 0);
  }

  while(true);

  return 0;
}
```