# How to determine if a value exists into an array using P processes

Tags: c, linux, performance

How can i determine faster if a value exists into an array using P processes? Here is what i have tried so far. I split the array into pieces so each child-process will check in a piece (divide & work). When the value is found, the child-process will write into the pipe. The parent-process will read the pipe and if there is something read, then it displays a message: the value was found. What i am trying to understand is: how can the other child-processes be signaled that the value was found and stop searching.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define P 10
#define SIZE (sizeof(elementsList)/sizeof(elementsList[0]))

static pid_t pid[P];
static int elementsList[] = { }; //some values

void findValue(int elemList[], int start, int step, int size, int value,
    int wPipe)
{
  int i;
  for (i = start; i < size; i += step)
  {
    if (value == elemList[i])
    {
      write(wPipe, &elemList[i], sizeof elemList[i]);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{

  int fd[2];
  int result;
  int nbytes;
  int child;
  int valueToFind;
  int wPid;

  printf("Enter the value to be found: \n");
  scanf("%d", &valueToFind);

  if (pipe(fd) < 0)
  {
    perror("pipe");
  }

  for (child = 0; child < P; child++)
  {
    if ((pid[child] = fork()) < 0)
    {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid[child] == 0)
    {
      close(fd[0]);
      printf("Child #%d\n", getpid());
      findValue(elementsList, child, P, SIZE, valueToFind, fd[1]);
      close(fd[1]);
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  close(fd[1]);
  int status = 0;

  nbytes = read(fd[0], &result, sizeof result);
  printf("Parent reads %d bytes\n", nbytes);
  if (nbytes > 0)
  {
    printf("The value %d was found\n", result);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("The value wasn't found.\n");
  }

  wPid = wait(&status);
  if (WIFEXITED(status))
  {
    int returnCode = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    if (returnCode == 0)
    {
      printf("Child %d exit status is 0\n", wPid);
    }

    for (child = 0; child < P; child++)
    {
      kill(pid[child], SIGTERM);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

P.S I have to implement this using fork()

Comment: Using threads would have a far lower overhead than forking processes

Comment: Is there any way to improve this version that uses fork?

Comment: @laura Methods for Linux IPC(inter-process communication): signal / pipe / shared memory / message queue / socket / semaphore

Comment: I am new into this and so far i only can use pipes. My question is if it's ok to wait until the first of the processes exits and after that calling the read or first make the read and only if is there something written terminate the other processes because the value was found. It's ok to use `kill`? I have edited the code with the second approach.

Comment: `kill` is OK so far. It sounds inevitable, but there are in fact different signals, some can be cought, some can't (`SIGKILL`,`SIGSTOP`). Install a signal handler for `SIGTERM` to do any cleanup (allocations may just be dropped on modern systems -> faster) and kill the same process by sending that signal to it. However, `CTRL+C` in a terminal does also send `SIGTERM`. You can instead or additionally use `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` for application specific purposes.

Comment: Why don't you describe in words what you are doing, in addition to showing all the code?  It would be easier to understand.

Comment: I edited the description. Hope that is enough clear now

Comment: If the reader process closes the reading end of the pipe, the process on the other end will receive `SIGPIPE`. Absent any custom handler it will just die. Add a handler to exit gracefully.

Comment: @laura : Thank you. Though the idea with `SIGPIPE` is a bit less generic, as it relies on at least one existing pipe, `SIGPIPE` could be handled the same way as a custom signal, if there are no cases, where a pipe error can be treated as non-fatal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new into this and so far i only can use pipes. My question is if
>   it's ok to wait until the first of the processes exits and after that
>   calling the read or first make the read and only if is there something
>   written terminate the other processes because the value was found.
>   It's ok to use kill? I have edited the code with the second approach.

`kill` is OK so far. It sounds inevitable, but there are in fact different signals, some can be caught, some can't (`SIGKILL`,`SIGSTOP`).

#### A possible solution

- Install a signal handler for `SIGTERM` to do any cleanup (allocations may just be dropped on modern systems -> faster) and kill the same process by sending that signal to it.
- However, `CTRL+C` in a terminal does also send `SIGTERM`. You can instead or additionally use `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` for application specific purposes.
- To exit that process, one should not call `exit()` from within the signal handlers. See this discussion for further information: [Can exit() fail to terminate process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8833394/1175253)
- To get a proper exit state, one should restore the default signal handler for the caught signal and then raise that signal again as in below example.

#### Example

```
void
fatal_error_signal (int sig)
{
  /* Since this handler is established for more than one kind of signal, 
     it might still get invoked recursively by delivery of some other kind
     of signal.  Use a static variable to keep track of that. */
  if (fatal_error_in_progress)
    raise (sig);
  fatal_error_in_progress = 1;

  /* Now do the clean up actions:
     - reset terminal modes
     - kill child processes
     - remove lock files */
  ...

  /* Now reraise the signal.  We reactivate the signal's
     default handling, which is to terminate the process.
     We could just call exit or abort,
     but reraising the signal sets the return status
     from the process correctly. */
  signal (sig, SIG_DFL);
  raise (sig);
}
```

Source: http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_24.html#SEC488