# Why is this simple code working with `exit` and is not working with `_exit`?

Tags: c, exit

Please, have a look at this sample code which is using a very well established programming pattern to redirect `stdout` to a pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        printf("A string");
        _exit(0);
    }

    close(fd[1]);
    char text[1000];
    size_t size;
    int p = 0;
    while ((size = read(fd[0], text+p, 1)) == 1) {
        p++;
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    text[p] = '\0';
    printf("%s", text);

    return 0;
}
```

The code, as it is, is not working. As correctly suggested in a comment by @kaylum, calling `exit` instead of `_exit` in the child process makes the code working properly.

Comment: `close(fd[1])` no, `close(fd[0])` maybe? in your code

Comment: @gsamaras isn't `fd[0]` the reading end of the pipe which I'm supposed to use in the parent process to read from the pipe?

Comment: You can `close(fd[1]);`after you duplicated it, it seems a bit cleaner to me, but I doubt this will change anything to your program's behavior.

Comment: What is `errno` telling you?

Comment: @DanielJour after `dup`? It says `Success`. I stripped all debugging information, but all calls lile `pipe`, `fork` and `dup2` succeed.

Comment: After `read` I meant. Also: `text[p+1] = "\0";` Your compiler must be spitting a warning about that line. Your probably meant to use single quotes.

Comment: Also you want to use `p` as index for the null terminator, otherwise you'll get one uninitialised element.

Comment: @DanielJour Yeah, you're right. Fixed p and single quotes. Still, after the read call errno is still set to `Success`, therefore the behaviour of the program is unchanged.

Comment: Call `exit` instead of `_exit`.

Comment: @kaylum is correct. That solves it at least on my machine. Adding `fflush(stdout)` also worked, I'd assume that `exit` is doing this.

Comment: @kaylum thank you very much. That solved my problem. @DanielJour, unfortunately I had tried with `fflush(stdout)` as well and that didn't work on my machine. According to man pages, `exit` is killing the process while `_exit` is killing the calling process, but still this behaviour is unclear to me, as the parent process (if I add more code) was still being executed (and eventually hang at the read call).

Comment: @kaylum can you explain while `exit` instead of `_exit` works? I searched for the difference between the two, and this answer actually suggest to use `_exit` in child processes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5423108/1433971 Thank you!

Comment: `_exit` may or may not flush standard IO streams (it's implementation dependent). `exit` is guaranteed to flush standard IO streams.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`exit()` flushes all the open streams as part its termination whereas `_exit()` doesn't flush - so any buffered output is lost when calling `_exit()`.

You can make it "work" either:

1) by calling `fflush(stdout);` to flush the buffered output *before* the call to `_exit()` or
2) disabling the buffering for stdout with: `setbuf(stdout, 0);` at the beginning of the main().

POSIX requires that streams are flushed by [`exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html):

> The exit() function shall then flush all open streams with unwritten
>   buffered data and close all open streams. Finally, the process shall
>   be terminated [CX]   with the same consequences as described in
>   Consequences of Process Termination.

Similarly, requires that streams are *not* flushed by [`_exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html):

> The _Exit() [CX]   and _exit()  functions shall not call functions
>   registered with atexit() nor any registered signal handlers. [CX]
>   Open streams shall not be flushed.   Whether open streams are closed
>   (without flushing) is implementation-defined. Finally, the calling
>   process shall be terminated with the consequences described below.

Comment: Note: Disabling buffering for `stdout` can dramatically slow performance if you're producing any meaningful amount of output. The real solution is usually "call `exit` instead"; `_exit` is only for very limited use cases.

Comment: @ShadowRanger There are cases where `_exit()` is useful (such as creating a daemon) or when you don't want the exit handlers to run when forking etc. So, what's ideal (`exit()` or ``fflush(stdout)` + `_exit()`) depends on the situation. But I agree disabling the buffering is the least preferred/useful option (except, may be, for "realtime" output -- otherwise, where a repeated call to fflush would be needed).

Answer (score 2):

`_exit` terminates the process without performing the usual cleanup steps that `exit` (or returning from `main`) does. It's suggested for use in child processes for certain circumstances because it avoids performing incorrect or unnecessary cleanup; when forking a worker to perform a short task, the parent task might have unflushed I/O buffers, and using `_exit` prevents the same buffered data from being written by both the parent and the child, mysteriously duplicating output. It also prevents `atexit` handlers and the like from executing.

In a C++ program, [it also bypasses stack unwinding, so RAII cleanup (destructor invocation) doesn't occur either](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/_Exit/); mostly meaningless for purely local resources (the child exits a little quicker, but that usually doesn't matter), but important if the cleanup affects externally visible state.

Answer (score 2):

`exit` is a C-level function that flushes and then closes every C-level streams (stdin, stdout and stderr are C-level streams).

`_exit` is a POSIX-level function that closes every system-level streams (descriptors like 0, 1, 2, etc are system-level streams). In this case, buffering is an system internal concern.

You've made a redirection to let `printf` (C-level function) finally writes to descriptor 1 (system-level), but `printf` buffers while buffer is not full and the C-string does not contains `\n` (it is your case). Then terminating by a call to `_exit` will simply lost the unflushed buffer content.

On POSIX systems, `exit` flushes every C-stream and then call `_exit` (which in turn closes every system-stream before really terminating the execution).

Answer (score 0):

Usually _ is reserved for implementations. _Exit was introtuced with C99, so you probably have to use a switch to make your coompiler conform to C99.