# How do you make address sanitizer report issues found in child process (fork -> _exit)

Tags: c++, c, fork, address-sanitizer

I have a program which forks child processes, but never invokes any `exec`-style function. This is by design. The problem is that the address sanitizer does not report anything it finds (even when issues are obvious) when the child terminates via `_exit()`.

As I understand it, calling `_exit` or `_Exit` is the correct way to end a child process which never invokes `exec`. If I change the logic for the child to use `return` or `exit`, ASan is able to report all issues found in the child process.

Is there a way to make ASan report what it finds when `_exit` is used?
Is this behavior expected?

Below is the example code I've been using to test this:

```cpp
// file: main.cpp

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    const auto pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0) {
        std::cout << "parent: " << getpid() << '\n';
        int status;
        wait(&status);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        std::cout << "child: " << getpid() << '\n';
        auto* p = new int;
        p = nullptr;

        _exit(0);   // No ASan output.
        //_Exit(0); // No ASan output.
        //exit(0);  // ASan reports leaks.
    }
    else {
        std::perror("fork");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Godbolt link: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dfsaTc7rz

- Platform: Ubuntu 20.04
- Compiler: Clang 13.0.0 (compiled from source)

Here is the command used to compile the code:

```bash
clang++ -std=c++20 -g -O0 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer main.cpp
```

I haven't found anything in the ASan documentation that points to a solution for this.

Comment: _As I understand it, calling _exit or _Exit is the correct way to end a child process which never invokes exec_ No, [almost] always use `exit`. The choice has nothing to do with whether `exec` has been used or not. There are callbacks that are invoked when doing `exit` (See: `atexit`), probably one of which is something for asan. Using `_exit` which does an EXIT _syscall_ stops the program immediately

Comment: So in most cases, `exit` is preferred. Doesn't calling `exit` also run the risk of corrupting the parent's memory? When would someone choose to use `_exit`?

Comment: No, once you do `fork`, the two processes have _separate_ [although similar] address spaces. Child could zero out all of its memory and _not_ a _single_ byte of parent's memory would be affected. `_exit` is largely for the library functions to use (e.g. `_exit` is the last thing that `exit` calls). Or, an `atexit` handler. That is, if I do: `atexit(myhandler)`, then when `exit` is called, `myhandler` determines that the program is in an _unsafe_ state (e.g. another handler would try to cleanup a temp file but actually delete a database), `myhandler` would do `_exit` to prevent further damage.

Comment: Try this program: `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h>  int main(void) {  printf("hello");  exit(0);  return 0; }` Then, change `exit` to `_exit`. Note that there is _no_ newline on the `printf`

Comment: Will do. I think I arrived at that statement about using `_exit` because of statements made in the book, `The Linux Programming Interface`. One such statement made in the book is _The exit() library function is layered on top of the _exit() system call. In Chapter 25,
we explain the difference between the two interfaces. In the meantime, we’ll
just note that, after a fork(), generally only one of the parent and child termi-
nate by calling exit(); the other process should terminate using _exit()._ Switching to `_exit` resolved an issue in a project I work on, but now I'm second guessing it.

Comment: I added `#include <unistd.h>` since it complained about not recognizing `_exit`. And now `"hello"` isn't flushed to the terminal, which makes sense given that `_exit` doesn't flush stdio buffers. My guess is that ASan really depends on the behavior of `exit`.

Comment: Yes, it does something like (e.g.) `atexit(asan_exit);` on or before the beginning of `main`. Then, all the analysis you've come to know and love occurs on the callback to `asan_exit` from `exit` ;-)

Comment: @CraigEstey this should be an answer

Comment: Here is one such post which lead to my use of `_exit`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5423108/5818611 - Do you have any thoughts about the question and accepted answer?

Comment: @CraigEstey: I'm also confused by your advice.  In most of the cases I can think of, the child should *not* execute any `atexit()` handlers that the parent may have registered.  Since there isn't any way to unregister an `atexit` handler, the only solution is to have the child call `_exit()`.  The current case is an exceptional situation.