# different output with exit() and _exit()?

Tags: c, unix, exit

why it showing different output???can anyone explain me in depth.

**1.**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
printf ("Using exit ... \ n");
printf ("This is the content in buffer");
exit (0);
}
```

Output:

**Using exit ...
This is the content in buffer**

**2.**

```
# Include <unistd.h>
# Include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
printf ("Using exit ... \ n");
printf ("This is the content in buffer");
_exit (0);
}
```

Only output:

**Using exit ...**

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422831/what-is-the-difference-between-using-exit-exit-in-a-conventional-linux-fo or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657667/exit-functions-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exit functions in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657667/exit-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we read `_exit()`'s documentation, we note:

> Causes normal program termination to occur without completely cleaning the resources.

This presumably would include flushing stdout.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know is STDOUT is line buffered, means it flushes the memory after getting '\n'.  Second thing is exit() flushes the stdio buffer while _exit() won't.

Now in your case, in first example exit() flushes the stdio buffer, So it is printing both printf output while in _exit() no flushing takes place so it is not printing both printf statement.

If you want to get correct output on the second statement, disable the buffering 
by putting

```
int main (void)
{
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
printf ("Using exit ... \ n");
printf ("This is the content in buffer");
_exit (0);
}
```